# c# Stream.Seek is giving me a 'NullReferenceException'

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I'm losing my mind over this one.  Can anyone spot an error in my code following this comment as it is giving me a NullReferenceException error at the point highlighted....  Thanks in advance for any suggestions...

```
    //retreive the picture from isolated storage
    Stream file = PicturesLoader.LoadFileFromStorage(PhoneApplicationService.Current.State[PictureCrop.PictureStateKey_Url].ToString());
    BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
    bi.SetSource(file);

    //load _pic
    Picture _pic = new Picture();

    _pic.Name = "TempFile";
    _pic.Url = PhoneApplicationService.Current.State[PictureCrop.PictureStateKey_Url].ToString();
    _pic.Height = bi.PixelHeight;
    _pic.Width = bi.PixelWidth;
    _pic.Bitmap = bi;

    //save the new cropped image for later use
    file.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    App._capturedImage.SetSource(file); <------  THROWS ERROR HERE, suggest file  = NullReferenceException ???????????????????

    //Get rid of the stream....
    file.Dispose();
```

Comment: Can't you put a breakpoint on that line instead of guessing? App, _capturedImage could also be null.

Comment: Both App and _apturedImage fall from the sky in this snippet.  Excellent candidates for a NRE.  The *file* variable is not. Use a debugger.

Comment: I would recommend this [guide on debugging in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336801). And perhaps a basic course in C# on top of it.

Comment: Thanks Claus, love it when a smart a** helps out.  As it happens I'm teaching myself c#, when you can code mainframes, i5's and VB come back to me sweet heart :-x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A shot in the dark: probably `_capturedImage` is the `null` one.

Comment: Glad to help. It happens to all of us: sometimes we just get blind and cannot see what's going on, even though it's right there, screaming...

Answer (score 1):

Either _capturedImage is the null reference, or (supposing App is a field or property rather than a class name) App is returning the null reference.